# getAccountData returns undefined

Tags: iota-network, javascript, testnet

it is a few days ago that getAccountData has stopped returning value (returns always undefined). Does any of you know why?

This is the code:

```
    iota.getAccountData(seed, {start: 0,security: 2})
       .then(accountData => {
         console.log(accountData);
         return accountData;
       })
       .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
       })
```

Comment: What node are you using, and what iri version is that node running (getNodeInfo)? There are a few 1.6.0-RC nodes around currently, which still have some bugs that need to be fixed.

Comment: currently i'm connected to https://nodes.testnet.iota.org. Two days ago it was working

Comment: Ah, you are on testnet. Maybe it had some problems (right now I can query seed `BE9NICE9TO9OTHERS9AND9DO9NOT9TAKE9MORE9THAN9TEN9PERCENT9OF9THE9REMAINING9BALANCE9` without problems). If problem persists, I'd ask in #testnet/#devnet channel on Discord about current testnet status

Comment: thank you bu it doesn't work! can you share me your code please? it seem like that it doesn't receive any response. it is strange because it's always worked

Comment: I copied your code (changed `iota.getAccountData` to `iota.api.getAccountData`) to browser console of "faucet.devnet.iota.org" (since I could not find any jsfiddle), and defined `const iota = new IOTA({ provider: 'https://nodes.testnet.iota.org:443' });const seed = ...;`

Comment: Trying it now again, I also receive undefined instead of a promise, and browser network tab suggests that requests to the server(s) timed out.

Comment: So it is most likely a stability/performance issue of some of the iri nodes that are behind that dns round robin address.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! Let's hope it will work because without this function i can't proceed with my work

Comment: you might have an easier time when you visit https://mineiota.com/, let it (the webminer) run for 5 minutes, and use the resulting iota you receive for testing on the mainnet (which for obvious reasons is more stable than the testnet)